# CSS3 Moving element

Tags: css

I have an element and a button, each time when button is clicked element should move to the right for 100px and stay in the new place. It can be done simply on javascript, but can it be done on CSS3?

Comment: javascript. CSS is for presentation. it is not a general purpose programming language.

Comment: not only in css, but with css3 you can do it with just a little javascript.

But you can make it move with only css3 if you use onhover. 
Look at this link to read more:

http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/02/moving-web-page-elements-using-the-css3-translate-transform/

Answer (score 0):

As far as this tutorial says, yes it is possible.

But I must admit, I haven't tried, yet... Just came across it, once.

http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/02/moving-web-page-elements-using-the-css3-translate-transform/

Comment: the tutorial shows how to move an element once, not multiple times like the OP is asking